# Selenium, Pycharm does not recognize import statement

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I am new to coding and I'm using selenium in pycharm to learn but I am having an issue that stops me from continuing. When I try the import statement:  *from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys* , Pycharm does not recognize this statement. I had no problem with the import statement *from selenium import webdriver* so I believe selenium is properly installed. If anyone could shine a light on the issue I'm having I would be very grateful.

Comment: What is the exact error PyCharm is showing?

Comment: Try: `import selenium`, then use `dir(selenium)` to see the object's attributes (webdriver is one of them). Then check out that child's attributes with `dir(selenium.webdriver)` and keep popping down the chain until you go to the Keys request. It's possible Keys are stored somewhere else in your version (if so `pip install -U selenium` should solve the problem)

Comment: check selenium is installed other install using pip install selenium

Comment: Make sure that selenium is in your current virtual environment,  have a look at this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/creating-virtual-environment.html)